# how to access global instance/variable via delegate in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I prefer to access the global instance/variable via delegate. ( I do not like the mode as 'extern NSInteger myInstance')

This means that all global instances/variables are in a delegate object. In cocoa touch, I know I can use

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

to access the global instance(myInstance), but I am not sure if it is same as the mode in Cocoa.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cooca, `NSApp` is a global variable representing the shared `NSApplication` instance. To get the delegate, you can simply use

```
id delegate = [NSApp delegate];
```

Setting the app delegate is pretty simple. In `MainMenu.xib`, `File's Owner` is the shared `NSApplication` instance. Instantiate your delegate class in `MainMenu.xib` (create an object and set its type to your delegate class), then drag the `File's Owner` `delegate` outlet to that instance.

Comment: I did as you said, but delegate still returns 0x0

Comment: @implementation AppController
@synthesize appDelegate;
 
-(id)init
{
[super init];
 NSApplication *app=[NSApplication sharedApplication];
   
 appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate];